# Inconsistent ordering of results across primary /replica for documents with equivalent score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created an index with a single shard and 1 replica. I'm running ElasticSearch version 1.0.1  and the cluster has 3 nodes  .

I noticed that occasionally  the ordering of results for documents with the same score is 
different based on whether the same query ran against the primary vs replica. 
The query is a match query.

For example when run against primary the result has :

```
{
       "took": 2,
       "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 1,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
       },
       "hits": {
          "total": 2,
          "max_score": 9.058382,
          "hits": [
             {
                "_index": "testdocs",
                "_type": "testdocs",
                "_id": "132898",
                "_score": 9.058382
             },
             {
                "_index": "testdocs",
                "_type": "testdocs",
                "_id": "132888",
                "_score": 9.058382
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

when run against replica:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 9.058382,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "testdocs",
            "_type": "testdocs",
            "_id": "132888",
            "_score": 9.058382
         },
         {
            "_index": "testdocs",
            "_type": "testdocs",
            "_id": "132898",
            "_score": 9.058382
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Not the change in "_id" in the result order above.

I wasn't able to replicate it with a subset of documents. I believe this seems to occur when the number of segments in replica is not same as that of primary.
In the above case replica has  21 vs 28 in primary. However both have the same number of documents so the data is consistent.

The question I have is, is this the expected behavior i.e for documents with the same score ES does not provide default ordering example: sort by _id ? 
Is the only way around it to explicitly sort the results by _score and _id or is there some other setting that i'm missing.